# Push Notification is receiving but background fetch not calling with pn_apns tag when sending in PubNub chat message Payload

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I had setup a chat module in my app using PubNub service not PubNub Chat Engine. Every thing is working fine, until push notifications come up. This app has Android version also (not built by me). I was able to receive a fully functional Apple Push Notification using *payload1* mentioned bellow. But it only works for iOS devices in term of Notifications, no Notifications for Android device which has GCM added for Notification.

So i did some RND and Found this [Link](https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006344) and used *Payload2* mentioned bellow. Using this both platforms get notifications. But now in iOS Notification comes on both foreground and background app state. but all of the bellow mentioned methods does not call, the only method is now calling is **willPresent** in foreground. I want to know why is that. Is is some thing Wrong with Payload or Tag or what ? Kindly help me out struggling for a week for this. Thanks in advance.

```
payload1 = [
            "aps" : [
                "alert" : [
                    "title" : self.loginUserProfile.firstName,
                    "body" : message],
                "pn_exceptions" : [
                    tokenString
                ],
                "content-available": 1,
                "sound" : "marco_alert.aiff",
                "publisher" : self.loginUserProfile.userId,
                "date" : Date().dateString()]
            ] as [String : Any]
```

```
payload2 = [
            "pn_apns":
                [
                    "date": Date().dateString(),
                    "aps":
                        [
                            "sound": "marco_alert.aiff",
                            "alert":
                                [
                                    "title": self.loginUserProfile.firstName,
                                    "body": message
                            ],
                    ],
                    "pn_exceptions": [tokenString],
                    "publisher": self.loginUserProfile.userId,
                    "content-available": 0
            ],
            "pn_gcm": [
                "data": messageString
            ]] as [String : Any]
```

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`

And

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
```

And

````
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)```
````

Comment: Please do not struggle for a week, rather, contact [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) when you have an issue. We are fast and efficient ;) Can you [enable logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) on both the publish and the push notification receiver apps and reproduce the issue and send logs to PubNub Support? Please reference this SO link in the support ticket so we can answer back here, too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes logs are enabled. I am defiantly contacting PubNub now. Thanks allot.

Comment: I have waited 2 days but didn't come up with any of there technical person. can you help me out with this. @craig Conover

Comment: I just replied to your ticket. Free support on the weekend? Sorry for the delay, we'll reply ASAP.

Comment: Well I have mentioned that the account i am working on is not free its paid. kindly review again.

Comment: OK, will do. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ahsan I want to make sure I understand the behavior you describe: notifications sent through PubNub using the payloads above work on Android and on iOS when the app is in the background. But when the iOS app is foreground, the notifications are only calling `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
         willPresent notification: UNNotification,
         withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
            @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)`?

If so, that is expected Apple iOS push notification behavior as described in the official Apple iOS docs. Historically, push notifications were intended for action outside of the apps active use, so this documented method is provided as a newer mechanism to interact with push notifications while the app is active.

[Apple has a diagram here explaining how to respond to this delegate method and cause the notification to present to the user.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions#2942083)

You may also want to look into [`UNNotificationPresentationOptions` as well for the available choices here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions)

Comment: I think you get it mixed here,
*notifications sent through PubNub using the payloads above work on Android and on iOS when the app is in the background.* Real thing is  **notifications sent through PubNub using the payloads above work on Android and on iOS when the app is in the foreGround and back ground both, but no background methods which I mentioned above are called.** only WILL PRESENT that you mentioned is calling in foreground.

Comment: As @gurooj points out, this is how iOS PushKit works. It would seem that things have changed in iOS PushKit (AFAICT) and that you just need to implement the appropriate code in `willPresent` and `didReceive`, as required. With that, it is not a PubNub issue because these are not PubNub APIs. But if you do find anything that is within the PubNub domain that can help assist in implementation/configuration, we are all ears.

Comment: Additionally, Push Kit is specifically intended for VoIP notifications and not simple push notifications. For that, use `UNNotificationPresentationOptions` as indicated by @gurooj